# CSV to JSON Mass converter in Python

Tags: python, json

I have a folder it is called DATA, inside that folder there is multiple .logs files and it is formatted as CSV . Now I want to convert every single .logs files inside DATA folder using Python.

```
import csv 
import json 
import glob, os

def csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath):
    jsonArray = []
      
    #read csv file
    with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf: 
        #load csv file data using csv library's dictionary reader
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf) 

        #convert each csv row into python dict
        for row in csvReader: 
            #add this python dict to json array
            jsonArray.append(row)
  
    #convert python jsonArray to JSON String and write to file
    with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf: 
        jsonString = json.dumps(jsonArray, indent=4)
        jsonf.write(jsonString)

os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Arda\Desktop\DATA")# use whatever directory you want

#double\\ no single \

for file in glob.glob("**/*.logs", recursive = True):
    csvFilePath = [] 
    csvFilePath = file
    

    jsonFilePath = r'data.json'
    csv_to_json(csvFilePath, jsonFilePath)
```

I can only convert one single file but there is multiple .logs file as CSV
In that list last one has been converted to JSON "T1555.logs"

```
T1003.001.logs
T1003.002.logs
T1003.003.logs
T1003.004.logs
T1003.logs
T1552.002.logs
T1552.004.logs
T1555.003.logs
T1555.logs
```

Comment: csv_to_json should be inside the for. Check your indentation

Comment: @GonzaloOdiard Thanks for the comment I edit it but it is not worked still same result

Comment: You're repeatedly overwriting the json file every time you read a new log file. Find a way to prevent that from happening.

Comment: @dsillman2000 I think you are right , great finding but I'm still stuck lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd re-arrange where you're traversing the files so that all of the results are stored in a single `jsonArray`, then written to the file at the end:

```py
import csv 
import json 
import glob, os

def csvs_to_json(csvFilePaths, jsonFilePath):
    jsonArray = []
    
    for csvFilePath in csvFilePaths:  
        #read csv file
        with open(csvFilePath, encoding='utf-8') as csvf: 
            #load csv file data using csv library's dictionary reader
            csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf) 
    
            #convert each csv row into python dict
            for row in csvReader: 
                #add this python dict to json array
                jsonArray.append(row)
  
    #convert python jsonArray to JSON String and write to file
    with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf: 
        jsonString = json.dumps(jsonArray, indent=4)
        jsonf.write(jsonString)

os.chdir(r"C:\Users\Arda\Desktop\DATA")# use whatever directory you want

#double\\ no single \

files = list(glob.glob("**/*.logs", recursive = True))
    
jsonFilePath = r'data.json'
csvs_to_json(files, jsonFilePath)
```

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: @Arda just make sure to mark my answer as accepted.